# Join/AND - Translate from SQL to Lambda LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm new in LINQ and Lambda and to be honest i don't know how to translate my one line query to LINQ lambda.Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

this is my one line query:

```
        SELECT *    
        FROM
   dbo.[Sales Invoice Line] innerjoin
            dbo.[Sales Comment Line] ON 
            dbo.[Sales Invoice Line].[Line No_] = dbo.[Sales Comment Line].[Document Line No_] AND 
            dbo.[Sales Invoice Line].[Document No_] = dbo.[Sales Comment Line].No_
```

Comment: That is not a valid sql query

Comment: Is this just the JOIN portion?  You need to post the whole query.

Comment: i know .i just cut the rest of , and i just need that line

Comment: could you post something that you have tested, and post a valid query.

Comment: @dpdragnev i edit my question

Comment: You still need a Select statement at least

Comment: check out this: http://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/join/Join-lambda-csharp.  You can adjust this example to fit your needs.

Comment: It still isn't valid. you are missing something like `[Sales Invoice Line] inner join` after the `from`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i edit the query :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter i edit the query

Comment: @dpdragnev my problem is not join , its AND - i dont know how put this line as Lambda : AND 
            dbo.[Sales Invoice Line].[Document No_] = dbo.[Sales Comment Line].No_

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multi-field join in Linq like this:

```
var List1 = new List<Class1>();
List1.Add(new Class1 { Field1 = 1, Field2 = 2 });
List1.Add(new Class1 { Field1 = 3, Field2 = 4 });

var List2 = new List<Class2>();
List2.Add(new Class2 { Field1 = 1, Field2 = 2 });
List2.Add(new Class2 { Field1 = 5, Field2 = 6 });

var results = List1.Join(List2, 
                         l1 => new {l1.Field1, l1.Field2}, 
                         l2 => new {l2.Field1, l2.Field2},
                         (l1, l2) => new {List1 = l1, List2 = l2});
```

The key here being the 2 lambdas `l1 => new {l1.Field1, l1.Field2}` and `l2 => new {l2.Field1, l2.Field2}`.  These create anonymous objects for the rows in each table that contain both fields you are interested in.  The join only succeeds when both anonymous objects compare as equal.

The 3rd lambda in there is just creating the object that gets returned as the "joined" value.  You could create whatever shape you want though, this one just creates an object with `.Class1` and `.Class2` properties on it containing the matched rows from each list.  You could flatten that out if you wanted, and / or add any additional properties that you need.

Full details on this syntax are available at MSDN's page on [joins using composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys).

I used the following 2 stand-in classes:

```
class Class1
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

A LINQPad file is available [here](http://share.linqpad.net/2wtgtp.linq).

Comment: tnx for all of this. just quick question , this my Lambda :odvm.SalesCommentLine = data.Sales_Comment_Line.FirstOrDefault(d=>d.No_ ==odvm.SalesInvoiceLine.Document_No_); and it will give me Comment Column and in my view im writting for ex:. @Model.salecommentline.Comment , But Comment Coulmn Contains null value and beacuse of that i will get NullReference , but i wanna tell my code no matter wat its null or not print out dat column for me,how can i do dat ?!

Comment: Try `@Model.salecommentline?.Comment`.  That will require C# 6 though.  If you are using an older version, try `@(Model.salescommentline != null ? Model.salescommentline.Comment : "")`.

Comment: dats wat i want, thank you so much for your help and your time